# My custom camera happen to crash after taken a few photo why is that?

Tags: android, camera

After taken a few photo, my camera just went black. Any suggestion of this?

```
SurfaceView cameraView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
Camera camera;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    cameraView = (SurfaceView)this.findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
    surfaceHolder = cameraView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    cameraView.setFocusable(true);
    cameraView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    cameraView.setClickable(true);

    cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v){
    camera.takePicture(null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    try{
        OutputStream imageFileOS = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/Galmix/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis()));
        imageFileOS.write(data);
        imageFileOS.flush();
        imageFileOS.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    try{
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);

        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);   
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    } catch(IOException e){
        camera.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: I think this question is not posted if phone's battery ran down.

Comment: I have upload the code and it's not a battery ran down. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the images you're saving are being saved properly. I had a similar issue where due to a bug in my saving code I was getting a NullPointerException and killing my camera activity. For more specifics you'll have to post code though.